# How to make click event for custom action bar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to enable click event for `custom action bar menu`.In my app action bar(am used `AppCompat` Library) i created `custom menus`.So i need to click this menu for call another activity.

If i used normal menu resource in action bar like below i know to how enable the click event.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose" />
</menu>
```

For above we can use `onOptionsItemSelected()` to acheive the solution like below

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_compose:
            composeMessage();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But my scenario am using Custom Menu.For this code i need to make click event.

### My Codes:

// menu.xml

```
 <menu 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:someNamespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/badge"
            someNamespace:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="@string/msg_noty"
            android:icon="@drawable/msg"
             />      
    </menu>
```

// feed_update_count.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flagImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/flag"
        android:contentDescription="@string/flag_noty"
        android:clickable="true"

         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flagImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/msg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/msg_noty"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

//Java Code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gk_page, menu);        
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.badge);      
    View count = menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.feed_update_count);
    View view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Please help me to solve solution.Thanks

Note : Am using Appcompat library (`android-support-v7-appcompat`)